# Log4net starts working when setting internal debugging on

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, log4net

I have .NET 4.5.2 Web API 2 application on IIS 8 server which uses log4net (1.2.13.0) for logging. I'm also using Windsor Castle. The problem is that log4net logging is working fine on production server for days, even weeks. But then, for unknown reason, it stops writing anything to log file. My log4net configuration is following:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="TextFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Logs\MyApplication.log" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %property{Guid} - %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="toaddress@domain.com" />
      <from value="noreply@domain.com" />
      <subject value="MyApplication production environment - ERROR" />
      <smtpHost value="my.smtp.server.com" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <lossy value="false" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR" />
      </evaluator>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %property{Guid} - %message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="All"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="TextFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I first tried setting write permissions to the Logs-folder for IIS accounts - without any effect. I first suspected this since this is customer's server and it's possible that some admin was messing around with folder permissions. Then I set log4net internal debugging on with following settings:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  <appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
          name="textWriterTraceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="log4net.txt" />         
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

It writes log4net.txt file, and everything seems to be in order. Some example from the internal log:

```
log4net: Searched for existing files in [C:\Logs]
log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0]
log4net: [.2016-05-26] vs. [.2016-05-30]
log4net: Initial roll over to [C:\Logs\MyApplication.log.2016-05-26]
log4net: Moving [C:\Logs\MyApplication.log] -> [C:\Logs\MyApplication.log.2016-05-26]
log4net: curSizeRollBackups after rollOver at [0]
log4net: Opening file for writing [C:\Logs\MyApplication.log] append [True]
log4net: Created Appender [TextFileAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [TextFileAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: Loading Appender [SmtpAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender]
```

As you can see, there was 4 days gap when logs were not written. But now the strange thing. The logging is now also successfully written to C:\Logs\MyApplication.log file, even when I remove settings for log4net internal debugging. So it seems that setting log4net internal debugging on fixed the problem. But this is not proper long term solution.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: Do you have any error messages - for example in Event Viewer - around the time it stops logging? Could be the process crashes and then once IIS is reset/recycled - it starts up again.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thank you for suggestion. Indeed in system event log there was a clue: "A worker process with process id of '3020' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.". My application was also using DefaultAppPool, but so is some other applications. I suspect that this was caused by some other application. I created own application pool for my application and if I get this problem again, I can be sure that it was because of my application.

Comment: It's a good idea to have your own app pool, but application pools do recycle occasionally (and so they should depending on configuration and usage); but it could indicate you might have problems with how you handle it for things like Log4Net if the pool recycles or an error happens - I'd start from there at least.

Comment: It seems more likely that the fact that the app started logging because you recycled the app pool by editing the config file, rather than from the changes you made to it.